# Dual Boot problems 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, windows-8, uefi, bios

my windows 8.1 loads up fine if I turn on secure boot but for me to load up ubuntu I have to change my settings to legacy mode and the reason I installed it this way was because it wouldnt display the installation screen in uefi settings. Any solutions to this problem? I dont want to edit anything yet on my own at this point before I damage my boot file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most computers let you disable Secure Boot without enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting. Look for an option to enable you to do this. With Secure Boot off, you should be able to install Ubuntu in EFI mode; or you can use [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a CD-R or USB flash drive, to boot Ubuntu in EFI mode. That done, installing the Debian package should enable you to choose between Ubuntu or Windows pretty easily.